# Max Activation Record on a stack

Tags: c++, record, activation

The question is pretty straightforward. It was a question I got on my programming exam at uni. Now, I couldn't find the answer anywhere. Do any of you guys have an idea of what's the max number of AR on a stack? In c++.

Comment: The C++ language is not defined in terms of call stack or activation records, and dies not define any implementation quantity that would limit levels of nested function calls, so the question is rather meaningless. In practice it is limited by compiler flags and/or available memory, but it is usually not a fixed number of ARs but a fixed amount of memory allocated for the stack.

Comment: @n.m. The question makes perfect sense on C++ implementations with call stacks. You may like to list C++ implementations that do not use call stacks.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin In order to answer a question about an implementation, you need to name that implementation. The answer would be "it depends" for about 10 implementations out of 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[An *activation record* (aka *stack frame*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) contains at least the function return address. For example, x86 `CALL` instruction pushes the return address into the stack, `RET` pops it. So, the theoretical maximum is `max_stack_size / sizeof(void(*)())`. Most functions use arguments and local variables which may also occupy the call stack, as well as [stack protection canaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow_protection#A_canary_example).

You can find out `max_stack_size` with `ulimit -s` bash command or programatically with [`getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, ...)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html).